# download images from wp-content/uploads/year/month/DSC_123.jpg

Tags: uploads

I need to download all images from website from all folders available. There is file on link: mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/DSC_1234.jpg. If I manually replace DSC_1234 to 1235 it shows next image, but it is not publicly available on original website so siterip software doesnt work correctly, only on this link. Is there possibility to download such files without manually typing DSC numbers and folders 2018/01 etc.?
Thanks.

Comment: are you the owner of the site and have access to the host?

Comment: If you go to mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01 do you get a directory listing? Some servers do, but it's less common nowadays.

Comment: But yes, you could write a script that tried lots of folder and number combinations. If it's not your server though you probably shouldn't be doing this, and if it is you should have a better way to get the files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers, when I try mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01 access is denied, but I found there is tool called Fusker for exact thing I asked. It was online tool, I just entered website URL and it scanned for such files and got em all. Hope this will help someone who searches fo smt similar. Thanks all

Comment: I still think the best solution is to log into your server (SSH, or your VPC admin panel, or similar) and download the files directly, rather than scanning for them.